Replacing a later line after matching a pattern on another line with sed
I am trying to use sed to find and replace in a large file python file I have.
The file contains many items in a list of dicts. Each dict contains a name field. I want to find particular names and then change one of the other fields in the dict.
Example file, simplified for brevity:
Books = [
    Book(
        name="foo-job",
        other_field=z
        min_tasks=Var(default=1, prod=4)
        max_tasks=Var(default=4, dev=238)
    ),
    Book(
        name="foo-task",
        other_field=a
        min_tasks=Var(default=1, prod=14)
        max_tasks=Var(default=4, prod=82)
    ),
    Book(
        name="bar-job",
        other_field=x
        other_field1=y
        other_field2=y
        other_field3=y
        min_tasks=Var(default=1, dev=4)
        max_tasks=Var(default=4, dev=8)
    ),
    Book(
        name="bar-task",
        other_field=y
        other_field=f
        min_tasks=Var(default=1, prod=42)
        max_tasks=Var(default=4, prod=83)
    ),
]

The other_field fields thrown in there are just to demonstrate there are an unknown and irregular number of lines between name= and the min_tasks line.
So let's say I want to find bar-task and then replace the min_tasks value in the bar-task entry with 0.
The sed command I came up with is:
sed -iE "/name=\"bar-task"/{:a;N;s/\s*min_tasks=(.*)/\1=0/};" books.py

This runs without error, but doesn't change anything.
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Why not doing all this in python instead of a general purpose text processor like sed?

You can use:
sed -i '/name="bar-task"/,/min_tasks/s/min_tasks=Var(default=[0-9]+, prod=[0-9]+)/min_tasks=Var(default=0, prod=0)/' books.py

Explanation:
/name="bar-task"/: Matches the line containing the specified name.
{:a;N;/min_tasks/: Marks a label a, appends the next line to the pattern space, and checks if it contains min_tasks.
s/min_tasks=Var(default=[0-9]*, prod=[0-9]*)/min_tasks=Var(default=0, prod=0)/: If the line contains min_tasks, it replaces the min_tasks value with 0.

This command will search for the line with name="bar-task" and then find the line containing min_tasks, replacing its value with 0.

Your explanation doesn't follow the answer you gave.  There is no {:a;N;/min_tasks/ portion.
Also, I dont need to be exact about the matching after min_tasks=.  It could be anything (e.g. dev=23, bla=34).  I just need to end up with min_tasks=0

The command can be simplified to sed -i '/name="bar-job"/,/min_tasks/ s/min_tasks=.*/min_tasks=0/' books.py which might be the best sed solution.

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() to populate array a[] with the text from the capture groups so we can then do full-field literal string comparisons:
awk '
    match($0,/^((\s*)([^=[:space:]]+)(\s*=\s*))(.*[^,])(.*)/,a) {
        if ( a[3] == "name" ) {
            inBlock = ( (a[3] == "name") && (a[5] == "\"bar-task\"") )
        }
        else if ( inBlock && (a[3] == "min_tasks") ) {
            $0 = a[1] 0 a[6]
            inBlock = 0
        }
    }
    { print }
' file
Books = [
    Book(
        name="foo-job",
        other_field=z
        min_tasks=Var(default=1, prod=4)
        max_tasks=Var(default=4, dev=238)
    ),
    Book(
        name="foo-task",
        other_field=a
        min_tasks=Var(default=1, prod=14)
        max_tasks=Var(default=4, prod=82)
    ),
    Book(
        name="bar-job",
        other_field=x
        other_field1=y
        other_field2=y
        other_field3=y
        min_tasks=Var(default=1, dev=4)
        max_tasks=Var(default=4, dev=8)
    ),
    Book(
        name="bar-task",
        other_field=y
        other_field=f
        min_tasks=0
        max_tasks=Var(default=4, prod=83)
    ),
]

It's always much easier to match the strings you want than to not match similar strings you don't want, the above is probably more code than you expected but it will protect you against regexp metachars in your strings, strings appearing in locations you don't expect, and strings that are substrings of other strings, all of which would produce false matches and change the wrong lines for all of the sed scripts in the question and answers posted so far.

without knowing what the actual python code looks like (the example provided is syntactically invalid and I don't speak python anyway), note that if Var( (for example) can split on lines the same way Book( does, or if there are multiple  a=b on a relevant line, your code also breaks

Yup, thanks for the heads up.

it feels like it should be possible to feed the relevant code into python itself and use its ast/pprint/introspection features to make the changes rather more robustly

Yeh ast was considered but it was a case of the benefit to automate with ast not outweighing the cost of time to do it that way.  I was hopeful for a sed command in < 10 mins.  2 days googling and a post on SO later, here we are :D

You should at the least see an RHS error, but the command has issues regardless.
See below for a few and check on https://www.shellcheck.net/ for more;

Extended regex is not enabled
Check that a file called books.pyE exist which would have been created from the flag -iE. You are instructing sed to create a backup file with an E extension. What you would want would be -Ei or better yet -Ei.bak to create a backup file of the original and still enable extended regex (ERE)
Rather than using outer double quotes and escaping the inner double quotes, why not just alternate quoting?
You begin a loop :a; but never branch back to it meaning your command never loops (if that was the intended behaviour)
The capture group which is returned in the replacement is not capturing the correct data but rather what you want removed if extended regex was enabled, but as it is not, no match is found as the parenthesis are literal.

This sed may work for you
$ sed -Ei.bak '/name="bar-task"/{:a;n;s/(min_tasks=).*/\10/;t;ba}' books.py


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -i '/Book(/{:a;N;/),$/!ba;/bar-task/s/\(min_tasks=\).*/\10/m}' file

Make a collection of each Book and then test that that book has the name bar-task.
If so and if it also contains min_tasks, replace the value following the = with 0.
N.B. As the collection is a multi-line string, use the m flag on the substitution flag to restrict the solution to a single line, otherwise all values following min_tasks will be replaced by 0 (including the closing book delimiter).

This solution is only for fun.
I commented on the solution of Nix Champ, that he can use
sed '/name="bar-job"/,/min_tasks/ s/min_tasks=.*/min_tasks=0/' books.py

When he edits his answer, that solution is "perfect".
Trying to play tricks with sed works bad. This one can fail:
# Wrong
sed -rz 's/(name="bar-task",.*min_tasks=)([^\n]*)/\10/' books.py

The \10 is recalling string \1 followed by the digit 0.
This only works when the matched name is in the last block.
You can make it work for matches in other blocks by replacing min_tasks by a unique character (like \r).
sed -rz 's/min_tasks/\r/g; s/(name="foo-job",[^\r]*\r=)([^\n]*)/\10/;s/\r/min_tasks/g' books.py

